# Express body-parser request.body returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

when i run this app and submit the form 'console.log(request.body)' returning undefined. i am a beginner in node js . can anyone please explain what i am doing wrong?

this is the registration form 
register.jade

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title.
            Fonebook
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js')
        script(src='/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    body
        div.container
            h3.
                The Fonebook
            form(method="POST",class="center",id="regForm",action='/doReg',enctype="multipart/form-data")
                div.panel.panel-info
                    div.panel-heading.
                        Registration
                    div.panel-body
                        div.col-md-offset-3.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3.form-group
                            label.
                                Profile Picture:
                            input(type='file',name='proPic')
                        div.col-md-offset-3.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3.form-group
                            label.
                                Email:
                            input.form-control(id="email", type="email", name="email", placeholder="Enter email ")
                        div.col-md-offset-3.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3.form-group
                            label.
                                Name:
                            input.form-control(id="name", type="text", name="name", placeholder="Enter name ")
                        div.col-md-offset-3.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3.form-group
                            label.
                                Password:
                            input.form-control(id="password", type="password", name="password")
                        div.col-md-offset-3.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3.form-group
                            a(href='login').
                                Already have an account?
                    div.panel-footer
                        button.btn.btn-info(type="submit").
                            Register
```

here is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test');

var uploadDir = __dirname + '/uploads';

var fs = require('fs');

var multer = require('multer');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var conn = mongoose.connection;

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.all('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');

})

app.all('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.render('register');
})

app.all('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
})

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (request, file, callback) {
        callback(null, uploadDir);
    },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {
        //console.log(file);
        callback(null, Date.now() + '.jpg');
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('proPic');

app.all('/doReg', function (request, response) {
    upload(request, response, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        //console.log(request.file);
        response.end('Your File Uploaded');
    })
    console.log(request.body);
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: but the image upload is working fine!

Comment: I don't think `body-parser` supports `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body-parser` does not support multipart forms.

[From their README](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#body-parser)

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:
>
> busboy and connect-busboy
>
> multiparty and connect-multiparty
>
> formidable
>
> multer

Seeing as you're already using `multer` you can access your fields this way:

```
app.all('/doReg', upload, function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.body);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your ans. Now i removed body-parser , followed your method ,but     console.log(request.body.email);
still returning undefined and     console.log(request.body); returning '{}' empty curly braces.

Comment: @ShafayatAlam - If you move the file input to be the last field in your form does it work? Could be related to this issue: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/146

Comment: i didnt have to , app.all('/doReg', upload, function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.body)
    upload(request, response, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(request.file);
        response.end('Your File Uploaded');
        console.log('Photo Uploaded');
    })
});


this works , but i dont know why :p

Comment: Looks like you're calling upload twice there. Maybe a good idea to remove the one after `/doReg` and see if it still works.

Comment: i noticed that , but i used the second one to log. and image was uploaded once. So i think no harm? 

btw i removed the 'upload' after /doReg .. image is uploaded but again no body